# Who was James Gordon's father?

Tags: dc, batman, gotham

In the Gotham (TV Series), it mentioned that James Gordon's father was a district attorney.

Is his father mentioned in the comic version of Batman? What information do the comics give about James Gordon's father?

Comment: I thought they said his father was the District Attorney for Gotham?

Comment: Oh, yes, I misremember, sorry.

Comment: That could be a loaded question since in comics characters often see minor details of their backgrounds rewritten by different artists or retold after reboots. Also, with a question like that you might need to accept "Lack of Evidence" as an answer (a "no"). I think there might not be any remarkable references to James Gordon (Sr.) father's profession in the comics.

Comment: His name was Mr Gordon if that's any help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no remarkable references (or no references at all) in the comics to commissioner James W. Gordon's father nor to his father's occupation.

Gordon himself is also the father of James Gordon, Jr. and the father (or adoptive father, depending on the continuity), of Barbara Gordon, the first modern Batgirl and then Oracle. He is even father of *Tony Gordon*, but only in pre-crisis continuity. As you can learn from his [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gordon_(comics)) the details of Gordon's history vary from story to story.

In spite of Barbara Gordon being his niece (eventually adopted) in some stories, the is not much information about commissioner Gordon's siblings (which could have lead to any clues about his father or his father's occupation) except for the names "Roger and Thelma", being *Roger* James' brother.

If in the TV show it was mentioned that his father was a district attorney, it must be a creation for the show. It does not come from a reference or well known fact from the comics. It is accepted that Gordon came back to Gotham after spending some 15 years in Chicago, but is never clear if he was born in Gotham. If the comic version had had a father that had been a district attorney, that would help linking Gordon to Gotham more, would have been more exploited in the comics and there would be more references to his father, and that is not the case.